# how to change return path in smtp mail settings in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, smtp

Can any one guide me on how i can send emails with a return path in ASP.net 3.5 / C# 3.5. I know this was possible few years back but now due to spoofing issues this is not possible. I have been looking on internet but no use. I want the emails if bounced, should reach my bounce mail box, which could be like Bounce@mydomain.com.

I am using simple smtp.

when i try to do like this:

```
mailMessage.ReturnPath = "test@gmail.com"
```

it gives me compile time error

```
returnpath is not a member of system.net.mail.mailmessage?
```

Answer (score 2):

mailMessage.From

mailMessage.Sender

Not the same thing, one of them will do what you are looking for, from memory, I cant remember which one, but Im pretty sure its the sender.

Answer (score 1):

Indirecly From and sender address will your returnpath and directly you can use this syntax:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.Headers.Add("Return-Path", "response@1234.biz");
```